# USB keyboard works in bios, but stops working when installing XP sp2. PS/2 not an option

Tags: windows-xp, usb, keyboard, bios

All,
I have an old (2007) computer (Dell Optiplex 745) on which the hard drive failed completely. I have a new hard drive, formatted to NTFS but otherwise blank.

- The USB keyboard works fine in bios.
- I do not have a PS/2 keyboard, nor is there an PS/2 slot on the computer.
- I have confirmed that legacy support for USB is enabled in the bios.
- When I attempt to install XP (from an Sp2 CD), the keyboard completely stops working. I can't hit "enter" to install XP, or anything else.
- I've tried other keyboards: all have the same issue.
- I am using the usb dual slots next to the ethernet port, but I have tried every slot on the front and back of the computer.
- I can successfully run Knoppix from DVD without keyboard issues.

I've seen other people online with the same problem, but no solution.

1. How can we resolve the keyboard issue so I can install windows?
2. If one isn't possible, how can I install windows XP to the drive from another machine and then move it to the computer I need it in?

Assistance gratefully appreciated.

**Edit:** I don't have an sp3 disk, I wish I did.

I would put 7 on it, but it's going to a field employee who REALLLLY doesn't get computers. He can handle XP and the minimal programs that are required, and frankly he retires in a few years so I'm not even going to try to convert him unless I have no choice.

Comment: You can use SysPrep if you want built-in tool of a Windows I assume you tried without leagacy support being enabled?  I also assume you have tried a SP3 disk also?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SysPrep, but it sounds ideal. Would you happen to have a "how to" type link for it? I did try it without legacy support, to no avail. Unfortunately I don't have an Sp3 disk. I do have Win 7, but as noted above, I'm not going there unless I have to because of who this computer is intended for.

Comment: SysPrep is well documented on Microsoft's website

Comment: Win7 in "Classic Desktop" mode looks almost identical. If he is that problematic about computers giving him XP with all its security problems is in my opinion irresponsible. Give him Win7 and sit down with him for a few hours to educate him about the differences. Tip: Let him do the clicking at his own pace: People learn better if they do it themselves in stead of looking at you doing things. Be prepared to repeat the lesson 2 or 3 times. Eventually they "get it". It most cases the "fear of change" is the biggest hurdle. When they notice it isn't so different after all they are fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have just faced the same challenge with Dell Inspiron 530.

All you need to do is to find PS/2 keyboards and PS/2 to USB adapter. This combination worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need XP drivers for the USB controller. XP doesn't support that out of the box as XP is older than the hardware.

Knoppix has those buildin so that is why it works on Knoppix.

You might have more luck with a XP, slipstreamed with SP3.
It is just possible that SP3 adds the extra driver you need but that is not guaranteed.
If SP3 doesn't work either then your only option is to build your own slipstream XP with the extra drivers added.

Why are you using XP by the way ? It is obsolete and out of support.
That hardware will run Linux or Windows 7 just fine. It is even 64bit capable.

P.S. There is on on-board PS/2 connector, but you need a custom Dell PS/2 bracket with matching cable because Dell uses a non-standard connector.

Comment: XP is older than the hardware? What? So keyboards have fundamentally changed? Then if that were so, he should get an old usb keyboard. But I doubt it.

Comment: re PS2: that makes sense, and it sounds like something Dell would do X_X  I'm not familiar with slipstreaming?

Comment: So research the subject.  It's well documented

Comment: @barlop: Not the keyboard, that isn't the point: XP is older than the USB controller on that motherboard.

Comment: how often have you seen this - newer than OS usb controllers not working on the OSs they are older than?  Note- he could get a PCI-USB card.  Also though I don't see how the reasoning behind what you say makes sense, 'cos XP was the latest windows OS in 2007. Windows 7 was released in 2009

Comment: @barlop: You really don't get it. XP does NOT contain standard drivers for the USB controller that is newer than XP itself. The drivers need to be installed, after the OS is operational, but without them the user can't install the OS. Classic chicken and egg problem. It happens all the time with new hardware and old OS. SATA drivers are another classic example, but NT4 and later has at least a mechanism to supply those during the OS installation. Starting with Vista that same mechanism can also load USB drivers, but you still need a keyboard (or mouse) to operate that mechanism.

Comment: @Tonny Yes I understand what you're saying What I asked you was "how often have you seen this - newer than OS usb controllers [DURING WINDOWS STARTUP] not working on the OSs they are older than? "  I am not asking about SATA(which was a new technology or SATA RAID and NT4.   I asked you about USB and Win XP.  Sure i've seen Windows load up and then recognize a USB keyboard, loading a driver, but it still recognized the USB keyboard at boot up.  Note my question to you.

Comment: Not to confuse you @Tonny  but as a side note as general info on this subject, I'd add that in the early years of USB, like 2002,2003, you had problems of USB devices at startup, and Ps2(and perhaps still is!) was more reliable. And in those days Ps2 was available on the computers. By the time Ps2 got phased out, USB became more reliable for recognition in the BIOS.

Comment: @Tonny And i'm not denying your experience, but i'm asking you "how often have you seen this - newer than OS usb controllers [DURING WINDOWS XP STARTUP] not working on the OSs they are older than? " (we were talking USB and XP).

Comment: @Tonny And by the way..You write "XP does NOT contain standard drivers for the USB controller that is newer than XP itself."  And you count 2007(which is of course very much in the lifetime of XP and pre Win7) to be newer than XP. What you are talking about must've been a problem experienced by millions. So besides your experience(How many times you ran into it - which you still haven't said). Can you provide sources for this?And,say he slipstreams-  **What USB Keyboard drivers do you expect him to add?** Most USB keyboards don't come with drivers That's the crucial question you should answer.

Answer (score 0):

Results:

Slipstreaming with USB drivers = fail. Slipstream disk worked, but keyboard was still not recognized. As barlop pointed out, there are no keyboard specific drivers to install, so all I could include were the generic USB 2.0 and 3.0 drivers.

SysPrep and drive cloning = fail. SysPrep ran for 14 hours and never finished. After googling the error, I restarted and tried again... 3 times.

Give up an install Win7 = success, except that now I have to deal with training someone who could barely turn on his old XP computer. I know some of you say a little training will solve the challenges, and 99% of the time i'd agree with you, but this is the 1%. I fully expect to be "fixing" ID10T errors on a near weekly basis for the next 3 years.

Anyway, thanks for the suggestions even if they didn't work. :)

For the certain people who had less patience, you might stop to remember that everyone has to learn at some point, so glib answers or referring some on to tech documents that are over their head are not helpful, particularly when the writer of the question has been polite and clearly attempted to research and resolve the problem before posting here. To those that were helpful, thank you.

Comment: Another thing you can try. Go on ebay and buy a cheap PCI usb adaptor. I don't know if it will work.. maybe you'll have more luck if it comes with a driver.

Comment: And another thing you can try, is Acronis Trueimage another XP machine. That can apparently make a generic image that can be written to a machine even with a different motherboard. (what is what apparently sysprep was meant to be able to do)

Comment: Acronis is like norton ghost but a bit more popular. Acronis has a forum good for anything specific to it.  What you encountered here was not impatience from those that didn't help you well, what you encountered was the arrogance of ignorance.

Comment: Another idea has come to me.  An automated install of XP